# UITableView loads same caption after scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a UITableView that displays content programmatically.

The cells load fine when first opened, but after scrolling they all show the same caption, which is, I assume, the last cells caption.

The underlying TableView that opens if a cell is selected still works fine.

I looked up the solutions on SO but they either didn't work for me or I'm too dumb to understand the Problem, which sees to be the reusing the cells for some kind of saving resources.

I will post the cellForRowAtIndexPath as I assume the Problem lies there, if any further code is needed please let me know.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
           cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSString *oneLine = [entrys objectAtIndex:position];
    NSArray *lineComponents = [oneLine componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];

    cell.textLabel.text = [lineComponents objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.8 blue:0.2 alpha:1.0];

    if (position < [entrys count] -2 ) {
        position++;
    }



    return cell;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not using the `indexPath` parameter at all. It should proably be:

```
NSString *oneLine = [entrys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I obviously got carried away with that unnecessary "position"-counter.

Answer (score 1):

try this one instead of postion

```
 NSString *oneLine = [entrys objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
    NSArray *lineComponents = [oneLine componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];

    cell.textLabel.text = [lineComponents objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.8 blue:0.2 alpha:1.0];
```

or

if it still not work then your array is not initialized properly. initialize it

Comment: He is taking the first part of the string separated by a semi colon.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
 if (position < [entrys count] -2 ) {
        position++;
    }
```

your rows in table are larger than the array count `entrys` and due to this condition your `position` is incremented to last object and after that this condition never gets called thus your `position` points to last object.
Could you tell what you have returned from your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method ?